# TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, lambda, rdd

I am running the below spark code in my jupyter and getting this error.

```
import re

def normalizewords(text):
    return re.compile(r'\W+',re.UNICODE).split(text.lower())

inputs = sc.textFile('Book.txt')
words = inputs.flatMap(normalizewords)
# wordscount = words.countByValue()
wordcount = words.map(lambda x :(x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y : (x+y))
sortedwords = wordcount.map(lambda x,y: (y,x)).sortByKey()
sortedwords.collect()
```

OutPut of **WordCount** will look like as shown below :

```
[('self', 111),
 ('employment', 75),
 ('building', 33),
 ('an', 178),
 ('internet', 26),
 ('business', 383),
 ('of', 970),
 ('one', 100)]
```

So first this I want to do is make is as below :

```
[(111,'self),
 (75,'employment')]
```

I have tried all possible ways of `lambda x,y : y,x` but not working any.
if i put righten side (x,y) in bracket it give invalid syntax error.

Comment: Try: `words.map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)`

Comment: the error is in line ```wordcount.map(lambda x,y: (y,x)).sortByKey()```.

Comment: Well very unclear, you want to reverse the k, v to v, k?

Comment: Updated the answer.It is still a little different to your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sortedwords = wordcount.sortByKey()
```

That's all you need, no extra lambda.

**UPD.** I think you can use this. However, why not use a DF?

```
sortedwords = wordcount.sortBy(lambda x: (x[1]), ascending=False).sortBy(lambda x: (x[0]), ascending=True).map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

Comment: I just edited the question to explain, why I need lambda.

Comment: You are doing bit different from what I expected but I figured it out from your code.```sortedwords = wordcount.sortBy(lambda x: (x[1]), ascending=False).map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))```.

Comment: But I can say the same to you too! This is the way. Success.